# angular - controllers .then function called after directive so no data avail async call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angularjs

Just learning angular.

I have a controller that basically loads some json. I'm trying to iterate thru this in my directive. I'm guessing I'm doing this wrong ? Any help is appreciated. In the debugger the foreach never gets to iterate as the scope has no data. I'm guessing its a problem with the asynch call?

I've played with hard coding the $scope.result so that it loads in the controller synchronously and this works fine. Its just the async .then call that doesn't seem to update.

```
 angular.module('dilApp')

 .controller('MainCtrl',  function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.result = {};

 $http.get('data/data.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.result = res.data;                
  });
```

The directive ..

```
.directive('myTable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            var html = '<table>';
            angular.forEach($scope.result, function (row, index) {
               .....
            })
            html += '</table>';           
            element.replaceWith(html)
        }
    }
});
```

Furthermore when I have a breakpoint on the async call for the json. I can see the "correct"  dynamic data loaded. I've stumbled across the $watch property for inside the link function but I cant get any luck with it.

EDIT - 
Added to the link method of the directive. I can now see this fire correctly when my $http.get method is fired. I'm just not sure how to get already rendered html from the link to update.

```
 $scope.$watch('result', function($scope){
                // $scope has new data how do I get the template to update ??
        });
```

Comment: If you add a `console.log` in your directive is `$scope.result` an empty object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the success and error methods of the returned $http object if you're just trying to set a value. These methods are specific to the objects returned by $http.

```
$http.get('data/data.json')
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    $scope.result = data;                
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log(data);  
  )};
```

Any errors that you're getting could also be helpful.

Also you probably don't want to couple your directive so tightly with your controller by referencing `$scope.result`. You may want to just pass in the data to render as an attribute, in which case [egghead.io](http://egghead.io) has some great tutorials on the subject (directive isolate scope).